# Arduino shows wrong voltage for 1.5V battery

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am seeing strange behavioral, now want to understand if this is something connected with Arduino UNO or with my code.

I am using Arduino to measure the voltage of simple 1.5V battery.
So I see that serial monitor shows 1V voltage instead of 1.5V (but the voltmeter shows 1.5V from the battery).
And when I serially connect 2 batteries the serial monitor shows 3V.

Can someone please explain what is going on.

This is my Arduino code:

```cpp
float voltage;
float batteryIn;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){

    batteryIn = analogRead(0);
    float voltage2 =  (float)map(batteryIn, 0, 1023, 0, 5); 
    Serial.println(voltage2);
    delay(50);
}
```

So shows 1V for single battery ( but should be 1.5V).
For 2 serially connected batteries shows 3V, which is correct.

Comment: I guess that the map function only returns a long type. So even if you typecast it to float, the decimal places are already gone. You have to make your own mapping function with a float return.

Comment: Tried this: float voltage2 = (float)batteryIn *5.000 / 1024.000; Still getting the same value

Comment: more precisely, now getting 1.7V.

Comment: If you are getting 1.7V and the `batteryIn` variable is ~350, then the problem is not with the code.

Comment: yes, right batteryIn is 347. So what can be the reason of wrong values? Issue with arduino??

Answer (score 4):

The [`map`](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.5/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WMath.cpp#L52-L55) function only operates with the `long` type, meaning it accepts `long` arguments and it returns a `long`.
Casting an integer to floating point value, won't make it magically have decimal values.

You need to implement a map function that operates with floats.

```cpp
float mapf(float x, float in_min, float in_max, float out_min, float out_max)
{
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```

```cpp
float voltage2 = mapf(batteryIn, 0, 1023, 0, 5);
```

In your case you could also simplify the expression and use it inline.

```cpp
float voltage2 = batteryIn * 5.0 / 1023.0;
```

Comment: Does not help, now getting 1.7V instead of 1.5V (for both solutions) (((

Comment: Most probably the issue is connected with arduino, any ideas how I can debug/fix it?

Comment: This code solved your problem of not getting decimals. Getting 1.7V instead of 1.5V is another problem. I suspect your Arduino is not powered with 5V, which this code assumes. Use the voltmeter  to check the voltage between GND and VCC.